# Assigning strings to a data frame as variables

Tags: r, string, variables, variable-assignment

See below

```
for(stockName in c("AAPLstock", "FBstock", "GOOGstock", "HPQstock", "MSFTstock", "YHOOstock")){
assign(paste(stockName), read.table(paste(stockName,'.txt', sep = ""), quote="\"", comment.char=""))  }
```

This creates these variables. Which is all cool

```
ls(pattern = "stock")
[1] "AAPLstock" "FBstock"   "GOOGstock" "HPQstock"  "MSFTstock"
[6] "stockName" "YHOOstock"
```

When I try to assign all of them to a data frame like below

```
df<-list(ls(pattern = "stock"))
> df
[[1]]
[1] "AAPLstock" "FBstock"   "GOOGstock" "HPQstock"  "MSFTstock"
[6] "stockName" "YHOOstock"
```

What I want is for df to contain these stocks as variables, not as strings. So the function below gives me the desired result

```
df <- list(AAPLstock, FBstock, GOOGstock, HPQstock, MSFTstock, YHOOstock)
```

But that requires me to type out all the variables. The thing is, I am going to be doing that but with more stocks, and I don't want to type the name of a 100 variables, and it's going to be a pain to change. So I want a way to assign strings that represent variables to a data frame using ls() or something similar.

I have tried Parse and assign, but they still assigned df strings rather than variables.

Comment: Why not skip using assign altogether, and create a named list using lapply over your vector of stocknames?

Comment: @Heroka how would I do that?

Comment: `lapply(stockNameVector, function(stockName) read.table(paste(... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [mget()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/get) to pull multiple variables by string reference.

```
df <- data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "stock")), stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)
```

But as mentioned also consider building a running list of stocks and rbind to a dataframe:

```
stockName <- c("AAPLstock", "FBstock", "GOOGstock", "HPQstock", "MSFTstock", "YHOOstock")
listOfStocks <- lapply(stockName, 
                       function(s) { 
                             read.table(paste(s,'.txt', sep = ""), 
                                        quote="\"", comment.char="")
                       })
df <- do.call(rbind, listOfStocks)
```